# prevent iframe from scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So I'm making a JS based game for the browser and there's a ton of content that I want to hide from the viewer of the game and I've utilized an `iframe` for this. The thing is in some browsers when you hit the **spacebar**, it automatically scrolls the screen down and when players hit the **spacebar** the inside of the page gets scrolled and what I want the players to see ends up off screen. so I'm wondering is there any ways to prevent the `iframe` from scrolling altogether. (I do have `scrolling="no"` as one of the iframe properties and it's not doing the trick)

I've also tried `overflow:hidden;` in CSS but that doesn't seem to help. it stops browsers in the iOS and Android browsers from being able to scroll off but in desktop browsers the problem is still there.

here's what i did

```
<iframe id="gameframe" name="Double Edge" height="576" width="1024" src="gameStart.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

in css:

```
.gameframe{ overflow:hidden;}
```

Thanks

Comment: How about showing some code? Did you defined scrolling property in css or html?

Comment: i have it defined in HTML.

Comment: seems like scrolling in html is getting deprecated but overflow:hidden  should work. So it will be best if you can make some example (maybe in  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: . is for class, # is for id.

Comment: durp..... thanks XD that might fix it :)

Comment: nope... it didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have content on the page that you want to hide from the user but need it to do something you should use *"display:none"*.
So there is nothing to scroll and you do not have to handle different posibilities how a user could reach your hidden content.

Comment: well... what if i have some content that's partway off the page but part way in the page. like as it stands, about 70% of one of the game assets is sitting within the game frame and the other 30% is sitting outside of the game frame.... how would i take care of something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem... If you have html elements in your IFrame you do not want to display, I would use "display:none" on them.

Comment: well one of the elements is half in the frame and half off the frame. I want to display the top half of the element but not the bottom half that's why it's half off the display area.

Comment: When you say element, what do you mean? A div or any other type of container?

Comment: images and divs mostly. My friend says this is a problem with FireFox and that there isn't really a fix for it. Oh well :/

Comment: I would try to add a div around the content that should be hidden and set this to "display:none"... There are so many ways you can reach an hidden overflow content, impossible to handle this. If it should not be visible, hide it!

Answer (score 0):

try adding this `onload`

```
var el = document.createElement("iframe");
 var iframe_style = "overflow:hidden; margin:0;padding:0;"
 var ifattr = {
        id: 'my_iframe', width: '520', height: '300', 'scrolling': 'no', 'marginWidth':0,
        'marginHeight':0, 'noResize': 0, 'border': 0, 'frameBorder':0, 'frameSpacing':0,
        'background': 'transparent','allowTransparency': 'allowTransparency',
        'name' :'my_iframe','style':iframe_style};

 for (var i in ifattr) {
      el.setAttribute(i, ifattr[i]);
 }a
```